# Error in logistf.fit in r what does it mean "determinant of Fisher information matrix was numerically 0"

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to do logistic modeling with Firth correction using logistf package in r. I have a data frame (df) with 110 predictive covariates and one outcome in the first column (nonR). I paste below the subset of this dataset that reproduces the same error:

```
Error in logistpl(x, y, beta, i, LL.0, firth, -1, offset, weight, plcontrol,  : 
  In iteration 63: Determinant of Fisher information matrix was numerically 0
In addition: Warning message:
In logistf(formula = as.formula(paste0("nonR ~", paste0(names(df)[2:10],  :
  logistf.fit: Maximum number of iterations for full model exceeded. Try to increase the number of iterations or alter step size by passing 'logistf.control(maxit=..., maxstep=...)' to parameter control
```

after I run:

```
lf <- logistf(formula= as.formula(paste0("nonR ~", paste0(names(df)[2:10], collapse = " + "))), data = df)
```

```
     nonR   APC ARID1A ARID1B   ATM  BAP1 BCL11B BIRC3  BRAF CDKN2A
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     0      0      0     1     0      0     0     0      0
 2     1     0      0      0     0     0      0     1     0      0
 3     0     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     1      0
 4     0     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     0      1
 5     1     1      0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0
 6     0     0      0      1     0     1      0     0     0      0
 7     1     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     0      1
 8     0     0      0      0     0     0      1     0     0      0
 9     1     0      1      0     0     0      0     0     0      0
10     1     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     1      0
11     1     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     1      0
12     0     0      0      0     0     0      0     0     0      1
```

Can someone explain to me what does that mean and how to solve this? I searched a bit online but no such info to address this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think a similar question was posed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570346/logistic-regression-in-r-using-package-logistf Similar to that question, it would help to have some (fake) data for a reproducible example.